# One liner *NIX command to pipe JSON object keys as arguments to shell command

Tags: json, node.js, shell, unix

I would like to have node modules installed only when you are setting up the test environment. The `devDependencies` and `optionalDependencies` will still install if you run `npm install <the-module>`. Instead, I will store these in `testDependencies`. To do this it would be nice if there was a *NIX one-liner to get the keys from the JSON object, and pipe that into the `npm install` command. This can be used for travisci and makes it so the default installation doesn't install these extra libraries.

How do you read the package.json file, extract keys to get module names, and run `npm install <keys>`? The package.json would look pretty much like this:

```
{
  "name": "the-module",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ejs": ">= 0.6.1"
  },
  "testDependencies": {
    "mocha": ">= 0.8.1",
    "chai": ">= 0.3.3",
    "sinon": ">= 1.3.1"
  }
}
```

The command to run would be this:

```
npm install mocha chai sinon
```

Trying to do something like this:

```
npm install $(read-json ./package.json | extract-keys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh)

Also, you can make your one-liner shorter by using `require('./package.json')` directly - it's the same as `JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf-8'))`

Answer (score 4):

Figured out a horrible hack :p

```
npm install $(node -e "console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf-8'))['testDependencies']).join(' '))")
```

Still looking for a "correct" way.

Comment: that looks like a one-liner! be glad ;-). But do you know about jsawk? It may be able to help you extract the nodes you want. I haven't had a need to use it, so I only know that it exists and from looking at some code samples that it might be helpful to you. See http://blog.xebia.com/2012/06/27/json-shell-scripting-with-jsawk/ for one view on jsawk. Good luck.

Comment: shorter version: `npm install $(node -p "require('./package.json')['testDependencies'].join(' ')")`